# How to detect the entanglement of two qubits by means of a statistical tool?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, measurements, quantum-measurements

Is there any statistical approach to help us in determining the entanglement of the two qubits based on the results of their so many times measurements? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have to decide on a quantitative definition of entanglement before deciding the best way to measure it. This thesis contains some of them: https://www.icfo.eu/images/publications/DT_08_01.pdf

Comment: Yes, if by entanglement you mean correlated. When you determine those variables you will have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A standard approach is to use [entanglement witnesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entanglement_witness). You can have a look at ([Gühne and Toth, 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2803)) for detailed explanations on how these work.

The gist is that, if a state $\rho$ is entangled, there is always some observable $W$ (a so-called *entanglement witness*) such that $\operatorname{Tr}(W\rho)<0$ and $\operatorname{Tr}(W\rho_s)\ge0$ for every separable state $\rho_s$. This means that there is always a quantity which can certify the state being entangled (finding the witness for a given state is a nontrivial problem though, see the above-linked review).